# Adding App Group Capabilities to iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-app-group, ios-extensions

I need to enable App group capabilities to one of my apps. I created a new group from Xcode and selected it, it has automatically added group capabilities to my App ID. But still I see two errors.

[image]

When I look up my app ID in apple site, I can see that app groups are enabled and corresponding group name is also correct.

How can these be resolved ?

Comment: I faced the same issue, and in my case my apple id wasn't have the permission to add the "App Group". If your account's type is "Member", not "Agent". then you need your Agent/Admin who has the main development account to add the "App Group" for you.

Comment: Can admin account add capabilities to the app id ?